# Qual é a melhor opção para um sistema que contém pessoa física e jurídica, cadastrar ambos na mesma tabela, ou fazer uma tabela para cada?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Qual seria a melhor opção em questão de performance, ou no geral? Como é feito?

Comment: No meu caso eu preferi deixar os campos separados, pra facilitar a validação

Comment: Sem entender o contexto, essa sua pergunta fica muito ampla e qualquer resposta fica baseada em opinião